# using the "in" operator for two dimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, operators

So I have the following array defined as follows:

```
        var a = new Array();
            a[1] = new Array();

            a[1][0] = "Computer Science";
            a[1][1] = "Computer Engineering";
            a[1][2] = "Aerospace Engineering";
            a[1][3] = "Engineering (Other)";
            a[1][4] = "Web Development";
            a[1][5] = "Computer Programming";
            a[1][6] = "Android Development";
                    //a[2] through a[n] defined similarly
```

and at one point, I'm trying to test if a string is contained anywhere in a[i], say "Computer Science", so I do the following:

```
                 for(j=1; j<n; j++)
                    if("Computer Science" in a[j])
                    {
                              //DO SOMETHING
                    }
```

However, this ALWAYS returns false, and yet I've verified that a[j] DOES in fact contain the string (in a[j][0]).  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Take it back to the basics. Try this: `alert('Computer Science' in ['Computer Science']);`. Nope! Also, `new Array()` should probably just be `[]` as in `var a = [];`.

Comment: Why [1]? Anyway it is more elegant to do `var a=[["computer...","computer...",...["android...]]` like ErikE mentioned in the meantime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is used for testing whether a *property (name)* exists on an object. For example, `"5" in a[j]` were true - the array has an index `5`.

You want to use the [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether an element exists in an array:

```
if (a[j].indexOf("Computer Science") > -1)
    //DO SOMETHING
```

Comment: Array.indexOf is not available in all browsers, notably not in IE<9. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility

Comment: So shame on IE, I can only say :-) Does my answer need to include the shim to be complete?

Comment: the shim is in the link of my comment, so I'd say no. You could've made the point in your answer. IE unfortunately is still an unavoidable nuissance for web developers

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = [];
a[1] = [];

a[1][0] = "Computer Science";
a[1][1] = "Computer Engineering";
a[1][2] = "Aerospace Engineering";
a[1][3] = "Engineering (Other)";
a[1][4] = "Web Development";
a[1][5] = "Computer Programming";
a[1][6] = "Android Development";

for(j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
    if("Computer Science" in oc(a[j])) {
       alert("test");               
    }
}

function oc(a)
{
  var o = {};
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    o[a[i]]='';
  }
  return o;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SRPEU/